# Permission denied for shared drive

Tags: permissions, samba, shared-folders

Fairly new to Ubuntu; I'm trying to share a drive containing video files on my tower with two laptops, all running 14.04.

When I go into the network and try to open the drive, I get the following:

**Unable to access location

Failed to mount Windows share: Permission denied**

The strange thing is, it was working a few weeks ago. Both laptops have brand new hard drives (they died) and fresh installs of 14.04.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this would be check the permissions on the actual file. Navigate to that folder in terminal type 'll'.

A list of all the files and folders in the directory will print out in a format like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x eric eric 4096 May 18 21:02 Android/
```

The string "drwxr-xr-x" represents the permissions on the file. If the 'r' in the third character from the right is missing ( is a '-' ) then other users do not have permission to read this file. You add this permission for a file by typing:

```
chmod o+r filename.txt
```

For a more detailed explanation of permissions, check:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: I'm having a problem accessing the drive, not individual files.

Comment: Try checking the directory's permissions? If that doesn't work, I've heard that sometimes you need to give permission for all the parent directories as well, but I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: yes, additionally all parent directories need to have permissions for others to execute ("x").